# Snake game, How to make a snake move?

Tags: java

I am writing a snake game, specifically, is a centipede game. It needs me to draw a snake and that snake will automatically move one line by one line.

I did draw a snake, and it can move from left side to right side. However, the problem is:

I can't make the snake changes line, if it finish the first line, I need it changes to the second line and which starts from the right side.

My code is like this:

```
private void move()
{

    myCentipedes[0] =
        new Centipede(Settings.centipedeStartSize, Settings.RIGHT,
              Settings.DOWN);
    myCentipedes[0].segments = new Point[Settings.centipedeStartSize];
    myCentipedes[0].segments[0] = new Point(0, 0);

    boolean dr = true;

    if (dr == true) {
        if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x < 30) {
            System.out.println(myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x +
                       "  " +
                       myCentipedes[0].segments[0].y);
            myCentipedes[0].segments[0] = new Point(x, 0);
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                myCentipedes[0].segments[i] =
                    new Point(myCentipedes[0].segments[i - 1].x - 1,
                          myCentipedes[0].segments[i - 1].y);
            }
            x++;
        }
    }

    if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x == 29) {
        x = 29;
        dr = false;
    }

    if (dr == false) {
        if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x > 0) {
            myCentipedes[0].segments[0] = new Point(x, 1);

            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                myCentipedes[0].segments[i] =
                    new Point(myCentipedes[0].segments[i - 1].x + 1, 1);
            }
            x--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that you re-create your entire centipede on every single move:

```
private void move()
{

    myCentipedes[0] =
        new Centipede(Settings.centipedeStartSize, Settings.RIGHT,
              Settings.DOWN);
```

Is re-creating the centipede every `move()` intentional?  Or should `move()` run the centipede entirely down the board, from start to finish? (If so, you'll need to add some *looping* to this method.)

I assume the `myCentipedes[0]` is simply a placeholder for future extensions, involving two or more centipedes on the board simultaneously. This sort of over-generic programming can sometimes make the code more difficult to read and write while initially programming, and almost certainly doesn't help matters. You can always re-factor a `move()` method that works on one centipede to a `move(int centipede)` method that works on a specific centipede and a `move()` method that calls `move(int)` for every centipede on the board. Or maybe you'll find it easier to place the movement code into the `Centipede` class, and need to remove the array indexes then and use class member storage instead.

```
boolean dr = true;

if (dr == true) {
```

`dr` will *always* equal `true` at this point. You might as well remove the variable and the test.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    myCentipedes[0].segments[i] =
        new Point(myCentipedes[0].segments[i - 1].x - 1,
              myCentipedes[0].segments[i - 1].y);
}
```

Since you're counting *up*, you'll actually copy the value from `segment[0]` through to *all* elements in the array, one element at a time. Can't you just assign the `Point` objects new array indexes? Starting from `i=centipede.segments.length` and counting *down*, it'll look more like this:

```
for (int i=myCentipede[0].segments.length; i > 0; i--) {
    myCentipede[0].segments[i] = myCentipede[0].segments[i-1];
}
myCentipede[0].segments[0] = new Point(...,...);
```

Some of your tests can be simplified:

```
if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x == 29) {
    x = 29;
    dr = false;
}

if (dr == false) {
    if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x > 0) {
```

If `dr == false` at this point, you might as well have written it like this instead:

```
if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x == 29) {
    x = 29;

    if (myCentipedes[0].segments[0].x > 0) {
```

But then the second `if` is obviously not needed -- after all, `29 > 0`.

While you're here, clean up all those hard-coded `10` with either a constant (`Settings.centipedeStartSize`) or find the actual length of the centipede (`myCentipedes[0].segments.length`).

---

Now that I've critiqued your current approach, I'd like to suggest a different tack:

Take a step back and break your problem down into smaller methods.

You've embedded two `for` loops that move the centipede one segment at a time by assigning to `segment[i]` the values from `segment[i-1]`. Instead of duplicating the code, write a new method with the body of the `for` loop to move the centipede forward. Make it take a `Point` object for the new first element each trip through the function. (Don't forget to make it count *down* rather than *up*.)

Once you've broken apart the `for` loops, I think it will be easier to make whatever changes are necessary for traveling left-to-right *and* right-to-left. You will probably want to write it with nested `for` loops -- one to control the vertical dimension, and within it, perhaps one or two new `for` loops to control the horizontal dimension. Make these loops work with a simple `Centipede c`, rather than the complicated expression you've currently got.

Breaking apart the larger function into smaller function will give you a better opportunity to test your functions in isolation -- test movement *manually*, with simple test methods like this:

```
move_forward(Centipede c, Point p) {
    /* code to move forward one space to occupy `p` */
}

test_right() {
    Centipede c = new Centipede(/* ... */);
    move_forward(c, new Point(0,0));
    move_forward(c, new Point(1,0));
    move_forward(c, new Point(2,0));
    move_forward(c, new Point(3,0));
    move_forward(c, new Point(4,0));
    move_forward(c, new Point(5,0));
    /* ... */
}
```

Take it slow, test every method as you write them, and I think you'll find this is an easier problem than it currently looks.

Comment: can i have your email address, I think this should be better if I send you my code and communicate with you directly.

Comment: My email address is not too hard to find from my profile -- but note that I neglect my computer for weeks at a time. Asking questions on the stack is probably a better approach to getting answers -- especially since you can get a better variety of answers that way, and answers can be critiqued, rebutted, and improved. :)

Comment: ok. fine. you answer is helpful!! However, I think I misunderstood something and didn't tell you. for update the location of the centipede, there is a way in run(), it's like                 if(currTime-initTime>Settings.centDelayHard){
        moveCentipedes();
        initTime=currTime;
      }

Comment: ok. fine. you answer is helpful!! However, I think I misunderstood something and didn't tell you. for update the location of the centipede, there is a way in run(),

      if(currTime-initTime>Settings.centDelayHard){
        moveCentipedes();
        initTime=currTime;
      }

this help me to update location every 1second, my questions now is I try to print out the value of x, to see how it changes, then I found every time the value turns to 30--29--30--29  it will never -1, i did used x-- in the right-to-left method, why???

Comment: You only have _two_ `for` loops in your current `move()` method -- and they should only move the centipede one space. You need to have _more_ `for` loops that can move the centipede further than the one space that will be executed here.

Comment: yes I know that, and I don't think I should more for loop cause if i separate the right-to-left and left-to-right, it's going well. and Now Problem is how to transfer them????  I used x to hold the position of head which is centipede[0].segments[0], but when I print out the value of x, it's always stable and never change when it finish the left-to-right side.

Comment: There is something I'm still confused about: are you running `move()` a thousand times to move your snake one step at a time? (In that case, get rid of the `... = new Centipede()` near the top.) Or are you running `move()` _once_, to move the centipede through the entire board? (In that case, you need to add some `for` or `while` loops to move the centipede through the entire thing.)

Comment: ok. Now I can move the Centipedes !!!  but still have some problem now, If it changes line, the whole centipedes will start from one point, for example all start from (30,1). or (0,2), and This cannot give us a beautiful view that the centipedes moves like this: **** 
                                                            ****** BUT now it's like : ********** (which changed line immediately with the whole centipedes.)